# Yoast is reporting fewer than 50 words for my quiz-like posts in WordPress. How can I correct this?

Tags: seo, wordpress, meta-description, yoast

I am new to WordPress development and trying to make a quiz site. I have a quiz plugin installed called WPquiz. I made a quiz with 12 questions, which is also more than 300 words (including the questions and options).

After creating it, I saved it and went to the posts, created a new post, copy-pasted the shortcut code from the quiz, added the title, and added the SEO title and meta description.

The shortcut code looks like this in a post:

[image]

But the main issue is in my posts and quiz page, Yoast SEO is reporting in red that there are fewer than 50 words or no words in my posts:

[image]

However in my quiz I have more than 300 words. How can I correct this? I don't have anything to write in my post, it's just a personality quiz site.

Comment: Can't you just ignore that warning? Yoast's suggestion is just for you and it doesn't appear to users or search engine bots at all.

Comment: Yes, but my  concern is , it will affect my seo ranking in google. Also I am planning to apply for google adsense. This will affect for my application too. Wont it??

Comment: You say that there are actually more than 300 words on that page.   It sounds to me like Yoast has a bug or doesn't know about the content from your plugin.  I'd think that ignoring the warning would be appropriate if that is true.